# Changing Beta from one tank to another

Tags: fish, betta

I am changing from a 3 gallon tank to a 10 gallon do can I just put him in the bigger on after a day of having it up and running or do I need to wait longer and can I just put him in it or do I have to us a bag first?  This is all new to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait.

A new tank needs to "cycle" as if it has live fish in it already for a week at *minimum*. That is, the lights, thermometer, filter, aerator, gravel & decorations, etc, should all be running like normal.

Once the new tank has cycled and all of the chemical levels (pH, ammonia, etc) are okay, then you can float your beta fish in the new tank. To float means to place it in a bag or solid container so that the water with the fish changes to the aquarium water temperature slowly. You add a little bit of the aquarium water at a time. Floating takes a half hour minimum, an hour on average.

As you have a beta fish with long, delicate fins, do not put any plastic plants with sharp tips in the tank; use silk plants instead.